# Sharepoint 2007 MySite Default Theme

Tags: 2007, my-site, theme

I've successfully created a separate theme that user can select for their MySite - The issue is that I'd like for the theme to become the default theme applied.

I've updated converted the TemplateID to be that of the original default theme. I was hoping that this would allow my theme to selected. This did NOT work.

I've followed the instructions found here:
Customizing MOSS 2007 My Sites within the enterprise

Not being a c# developer this is a bit much and over the top. I do not need to create a full feature that can be enabled through the backend and whatnot, but rather over-write the current default theme.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The "default" theme is actually no theme at all - just the ordinary styles. I don't quite know what you were describing regarding the TemplateID.

To change the theme in My Sites in 2007, the standard way would be to use a Feature Receiver, and that C# would change your My Site. To activate that feature, you'd use a technique called 'Feature Stapling', so that when sites using a certain Site Definition are created, the new feature would be activated.

This is a developer activity. The good news is that if you're happy with the existing site's master page, and the web parts that are shown, then the code is much simpler than [the article I think you meant to link to](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=794) (I don't think Overflow liked the {} in the URL!). In fact, the main bit of the code in the feature receiver would [be like this](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/17/programmatically-apply-a-default-theme-in-sharepoint/) - but this does rely on you not wanting to change the master page, or the web parts shown.

So it is a developer task, though not a huge one. It isn't "over the top" because this is the best way of doing it, after you factor in that each My Site is a seperate Site Collection (and they don't share settings), and that you can't modify the out of the box Site Definition for My Sites directly (which invalidates your support). It's annoying, but it is the best way.

Comment: +1 for the feature stapling technique. I've done exactly this lately, where I had a branding project that was pure CSS (no custom master pages), a little bit of code to wire it up, and a separate Web Application scoped feature to staple it to the Personal Site Template in the MySites Web App. Works a dream.